# Flutter app uploading image to Firebase Storage with Shopify App Counterpart - Image: Media processing failed

Tags: firebase, flutter, shopify, firebase-storage, shopify-app

I'm trying to add products with photos from a url, and I'm getting a media processing error. The photos work everywhere else I use them, but they don't seem to get processed by Shopify.

[image]

I've tried uploading as a base64 file as well and verified that the base64 file isn't broken here: hhttps://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Here's the images i'm testing with:

[base64](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sellar-ab2e6.appspot.com/o/wkj0WSaKeISKMwprK3XJevXzDWe2%2FrQ6H5Zp7GsAzu03Bk0Yl%2FM9GIyN6awGdCIKyPvkfW%2FtX526SAaeMwBL215R9qj-base64?alt=media&token=395c7b77-7213-4330-a234-3a6ec55c8811)

[jpeg](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sellar-ab2e6.appspot.com/o/wkj0WSaKeISKMwprK3XJevXzDWe2%2FrQ6H5Zp7GsAzu03Bk0Yl%2FM9GIyN6awGdCIKyPvkfW%2FtX526SAaeMwBL215R9qj-original.jpg?alt=media&token=fa203c76-3028-4d54-ba64-973f79e70df7)

code I'm using to upload images:

```
// upload compressed photo
            var compressedJpeg = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
              item.photoByteData.buffer.asUint8List(),
              format: CompressFormat.jpeg,
            );
            uploadTask = photoStorageReference.putData(
              Uint8List.fromList(compressedJpeg),
              StorageMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
            );
            await uploadTask.onComplete;

// upload base64 image
            final base64Path =
                join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, 'base64_original');
            File base64File = File(base64Path);
            base64File.writeAsStringSync(base64Encode(compressedJpeg));
            uploadTask = base64StorageReference.putFile(
              base64File,
              StorageMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
            );
            await uploadTask.onComplete;
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Comment: I could upload the image via URL, no error.

Comment: @Vladimir really? did you use the base64 or the jpeg? And how did you go about uploading it?

Comment: I used JPG, via admin panel

Comment: did you add it via url or did you download the image first?

Comment: Tried both. Uploaded once using URL and once from the computer.

Comment: For me, it's working if I'm creating a brand new product. But if I create a product and then save it and try to update the product media with a link, it fails

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to shopify support chat, query strings in the url are not supported.